# Is there a way not to keep payed files on device using In App Billing on Android?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am creating an app where my users could buy additional content(data). This content saved for example in xml file. So I want to achieve such behavior that when the user buy part of payed content, my app receives this xml file, parse it and display data. Is there a way not to keep this file on device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement InApp purchase to view this link(or load XML data in another activity) and have a unique SKU for each link to be purchased. You can find a Status check, if the link SKU is purchase or not, in the InAppBilling Library. So do a status check when ever the link is clicked, if not purchased popup the user to purchase, else load the XML data from online.

Is there a way not to keep this file on device?
Load the XML file directly from Online. Or Download XML once and save the XML content(Not file) in the DB.

Cheer :)

Comment: Load XML file from where ? I don't have a server to process such requests

Comment: Your query is not to save the XML file in SD Card right? So you should have a Local DB in the application to load the content in the application. The Local DB should be pre-loaded with XML content.

Comment: I wrote in the title of the question that I don't want to keep payed content on device until user buy it.

Comment: Option 1:  Download XML and save the XML content(Not file) in the DB or as a file in Sd card, after Successful InApp purchase.
Option 2: Keep a encrypted XML content in DB till user purchases, decrypt the content only if the user purchases.

Comment: Option 1:  Download XML and save the XML content(Not file) in the DB or as a file in Sd card, after Successful InApp purchase. (Save the file in some free online storage Dropbox or Google Drive, which can be accessed only after authentication)
Option 2: Keep a encrypted XML content in DB till user purchases, decrypt the content only if the user purchases.

Comment: Yeah, this is just the option, but not the way out, unfortunately that's not what I need. Documentation says "You can use the service to sell a wide range of content, including downloadable content such as media files or photos..." What does that all mean ?

Comment: Wide range of Contents: Without using Server? and should not save in Device as well?

Comment: But word "downloadable" making me confused about that!

Comment: Did you get any idea?

Comment: No, I refused of using In-app purchase and implemented it in my own way.